# Catch name of element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, element

I have a form select element with name `field_p_payment[value]` and i need to catch this element and reset the select box , i used the following code ,

```
document.getElementsByName("field_p_payment[value]").selectedIndex='0'
```

But it doesnt seem worked , i also tried the jquery version as

```
$('[name="field_p_payment[value]"]').attr("selectedIndex","0");
```

But `$('[name="field_p_payment[value]"]').prop("selectedIndex","0");` works .

But i cant use prop because am using an oldest version of jquery .Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually `getElementsByName` returns the results in a HTML collection. So try,

```
document.getElementsByName("field_p_payment[value]")[0].selectedIndex='0'
```

Also read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) for more information.

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich Glad to help!

Comment: Removed my duplicate ,answer +1